# Which regex engine first introduced the lookaround?

Tags: regex, perl

My question is described above as title, that's all.

I think the answer is **Perl's regexp engine**, but I don't know when Perl introduces lookaround. And I guess Perl implements lookahead operator only at first and implements lookbehind after.

Another my concern: should I ask to Computer Science Stack Exchange instead?

Comment: Just to clarify, your questions are: `Which regex engine first introduced the lookaround?` and `Which lookaround assertion was first created?`

Comment: Yes, this doesn't really fit here. It's not a concrete programming problem. Either CS or Software Engineering.

Comment: This isn't a question about CS theory, but about actual programming language versions. That makes SO the most appropriate SE site for this question. /// That said, it's a rather broad question. It doesn't look like the OP tried to establish when lookaround assertions were added to Perl or anything else. They didn't even verify their (incorrect) assumption that lookbehind was implemented after lookahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression lookahead and lookbehind assertions in perl were introduced in Perl 5.000 in 1994.  From the `perlre` in version 5.000 from https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/a0d0e21ea6ea90a22318550944fe6cb09ae10cda

> The patterns used in pattern matching are regular expressions such as
>   those supplied in the Version 8 regexp routines.
>   (In fact, the routines are derived from Henry Spencer's freely redistributable reimplementation of the V8 routines.)

Henry Spencer's regular expression library code is available at https://garyhouston.github.io/regex/  You are encouraged to look through the commit logs to get the actual dates you are looking for.  The [wikipedia Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#History) article dates those libraries to 1986.